# MYSQL and PHP group results by field data

Tags: php, arrays, loops, group-by, mysqli

I am trying to create reports based on data from a log in the database that looks like:

id |    student    |    type        |    marks
1         23494           CAT1               50
2          23495             CAT1               20
3          23494             CAT2                35
4          23495             MIDTERM       40

My select statement so far looks like this:

```
$res = @mysqli_query ($dbc, "SELECT id, student, type, GROUP_CONCAT(marks) AS mark, GROUP_CONCAT(type) AS types FROM log WHERE class = '1' AND term = '2' GROUP BY student DESC");

// Fetch and print all the records....<br>
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        echo '<tr>
            <td align="left">'. $row['student'] .'</td>';

        //$exams = split(",", $row['exams']); // 4,3,1,2
        $marks = split(",", $row['mark']); // 10,20,40,50

        foreach( $marks as $mark ) {
             echo '
                   <td align="left">' . $mark . '</td>
                ';
        }

        echo '</tr>';

} //End LOOP

//Then i end table
```

So far the data displays like so:

STUDENT | CAT1 | CAT2 | MIDTERM 
23494          50          35
23495          20          40

The problem is that the code is not arranging 'marks' according to 'type' (look at MIDTERM output for id 4 and corresponding display).

Question:

How do i display the results by student, followed by marks in the appropriate cell/group like so:?

STUDENT | CAT1 | CAT2 | MIDTERM 
23494          50          35
23495          20                       40

Thanks in Advance Guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to keep logic away from layout. It's generally good practice to first gather the data you need, and then display it.

Using `GROUP_CONCAT` can make things more complicated, since you do not know how many results you will get for each student, nor will you be able to easily identify which marks are of what type.

With that in mind I've created a solution. You'll still need to extend the query of course.

```
$query = 'SELECT student, type, marks FROM log';
$res = mysqli_query($query);
$studentMarks = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $studentMarks[$row['student']][$row['type']] = $row['marks'];
}

// Now $studentMarks should look like:
// $studentMarks = array(
//    23494 => array('CAT1' => 50, 'CAT2' => 35)
//  , 23495 => array('CAT1' => 20, 'MIDTERM' => 40)
// );    

echo '<table><thead><tr>';
echo '<td>Student</td><td>CAT1</td><td>CAT2</td><td>MIDTERM</td>';
echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';

foreach($studentMarks as $studentId => $marks)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>', $studentId, '</td>';
    echo '<td>', (isset($marks['CAT1']) ? $marks['CAT1'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
    echo '<td>', (isset($marks['CAT2']) ? $marks['CAT2'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
    echo '<td>', (isset($marks['MIDTERM']) ? $marks['MIDTERM'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Arjan, I am currently testing your logic. Though my first test using your code returns only $studentId. Let me explore a bit more and I will get back to you.

Comment: I still can't get your logic to display the marks as associated to type. Any other ideas, please?

Comment: I'm not sure why the code doesn't seem to work. Just to be on the safe side, I've added a few comment lines in the code to show what `$studentMarks` should look like (based on the question). When it looks like that, the code will work. If you don't understand parts of the code, please explain which parts need clarification and I'll provide that.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was able to get your code working. I was initially lost at the foreach output but it was just an error in my part while integrating my database. I can now safely say problem solved. Cheers.